# Single sign on for custom ASP sites in IFRAME in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

For several case types / entities, additional data is being displayed in IFRAMEs inside the CRM pages. This data is partially based on CRM stuff and partially comes from additional data sources associated with a CRM entity.

**Edit:** The IFRAME content is located on another server.

The question is: How can I use CRM as a session and role provider so, that the ASP page inside the IFRAME can 'ask' CRM whether the current user is logged on to CRM and allowed to see the data (based on the access-right etc. associated with the case).

Can you give me a hint where to search? (I'm new to this topic.)

**Edit:** Microsoft Dynamics® CRM 2011 (5.0.96881157), Authentication: On-Premise

Comment: it is important to know what CRM version do you use (4.0 / 2011) and what is authentication type (On Premise / IFD and Claims based authentication)?

Comment: I know this question is more than 3 years old, but have you reached any answer? would you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 1):

Official Microsoft POV:

Adding custom webpages and supporting files to the \ISV\ folder is fully supported but deprecated. The ISV folder is maintained for backward (legacy) compatibility only. Any webpages or other custom code in that folder must use the 2007 ASMX web service endpoint. For more information, see [Upgrade Code in the ISV folder to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309571.aspx).

Some more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx

From 4.0:
It should work if you put the output in the `ISV` folder of the CRM web folder. Merge the web.config of your application with the web.config of the CRM web folder if you have any custom settings (unsupported) or preferrably remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately the ASP app is on another server and not in the ISV